# execution terminated in middle when the API is Called concurrently using HttpClient

Tags: c#, multithreading, web-services, concurrency, dotnet-httpclient

I am having a problem while calling a webService using HttpClient from my another webservice hosted in the same server.

The Scenario is, There is a REST webService, Lets Say "WebService1" that receives the request from multiple clients to create the PDF. 
The WebService1 further calls the another webservice "BackendWebService" to create the PDF Doument. This backend WebService references the third party Library to create the PDF.

What is happening now is if a single user calls the WebService1 with 10 requests, then there is no problem. All the requests are processed successfully.
But if there are involvement of multiple users and sends the request to WebService1 **simultaneously**, then **only few records are processed successfully, some of the records are 
terminated in middle**. It seems the code is not executed completely and the application is terminated without completing the whole process.

Why this is happening ? Please help. I have already created only one static instance of HttpClient, but still no Luck.

WebService1 calls the BackendWebService as below:

*for each number of PDF request from client:*

[This is how WebService calls the BackendWebService](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bkQFo.png)

Comment: need more information, there must be an exception being thrown that is not being logged properly

Comment: Also worth to mention that `BaseAdress` and `DefaultRequestHeaders` are probably not thread-safe.

Comment: @Eric Walter, The strange thing is, i have been monitoring the IIS logs, Event viewer etc, but unfortunately there is no any error logged.
Also, there is try catch block when exception is caught and logged. But lo logs are there !

Comment: Could very well be deadlocking. Don't ever use `.Result` with HttpClient - use `async/await`.

Comment: @Todd Menier,
I tried with implementing async/await too, but it also does not work for multiple concurrent calls. Works only for the single instance. If 10 records are processed with single calls, then it works but then these records are distributed in 5 instance (2 in each) and called concurrently, then it fails, only 6/7 records are processed.

Comment: Are you able to run "BackendWebService" in debug mode and break on exceptions? I think there's a scalability problem there - maybe the 3rd-party library wasn't designed for this usage.

Comment: @ToddMenier ,Its hard to debug BackendWebservice in multi threaded environment. But for a single instance , it runs properly without any issues. No error an no exceptions at all.

Comment: Hard to debug because you don't have access to the source code?

Comment: @ToddMenier , No I do have Source and its created by myself ! Could you suggest how you want to debug it? Because, normal debug is working fine.

Comment: Further More, one thing i noticed: I just checked the IIS logs inside C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVCN....I noticed that the sc-status is 400, which is BAD Request.

But why only in the case of Concurrency ? Why not in case when the all 10 records are processed by single user instance ?

Comment: What's throwing a 400? WebService1 or BackendWebService?

Comment: Need clarification: "some of the records are terminated in middle" - What does that mean exactly? You're getting back half-rendered PDFs? "the application is terminated without completing the whole process" - Which application is terminated?

Comment: @ToddMenier, status 400 is found to be  logged in IIS Logs in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVCN, for those failed requests only.

The library that creates the PDF is terminated without completing its whole task. It writes logs in different stages such as "Starting Library with at datetime....,  Pdf creation process started for PDFId 2.... Process completed... and so on". But For some requests, all steps are completed and PDF is generated. For some requests only first logs is written and  and then no more steps are executed and nothing has happened.

The half pdf is NOT RENDERED in any cases.

Comment: What PDF library are you using?

Comment: @ToddMenier Its EO.PDF Library from https://www.essentialobjects.com/doc/eo.pdf.aspx.

Smetimes the process seems to be terminated just after the BackendWebService receive the request, even before this PDF library is called. I i guess its may not also be the problem with this PDF library alone.

Comment: @ToddMenier, Furthermore, i find that the BackendwebService is returing error code 400 i.e the BAD REQUEST as response. But this is happening only when the request are sent concurrently, not for the single instance. What could be the case ? Also bad requests are normally for malformed json or incorrect request which is not the case here. Is there any way to find why the server respond with bad request ?

Comment: "i guess its may not also be the problem with this PDF library alone." You shouldn't have to guess. Test it in isolation. That is, without the HTTP services. Call the PDF generator from 5, 10, 20 (whatever) different threads concurrently and see if you can get it to fail.

Comment: @ToddMenier, Thanks for your effort, i found the reason of the issue finally !

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the reason of this issue.

There was an concurrency issue in the library (a custom library called processhandler.dll ) referenced in BackendWebService while writing log in to the txt file by multiple processes. And when there is an exception in this referenced library, the process was terminating without any information in IIS or in application level logs as well.